# Warning Variable 'csCryptoStream' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime

Tags: vb.net, encryption, filestream

Im new to VB.Net. I am trying to debug my project, but I get a warning: Variable 'csCryptoStream' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime

How can I fix it?

```
Private Sub EncryptOrDecryptFile(strInputFile As String, strOutputFile As String, bytKey As Byte(), bytIV As Byte(), Direction As crypt.CryptoAction)
    ' The following expression was wrapped in a checked-statement
    Try
        Me.fsInput = New FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Me.fsOutput = New FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        Me.fsOutput.SetLength(0L)
        Dim bytBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(4096) {}
        Dim lngBytesProcessed As Long = 0L
        Dim lngFileLength As Long = Me.fsInput.Length
        Dim cspRijndael As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
        Me.pbStatus.Value = 0
        Me.pbStatus.Maximum = 100
        Dim csCryptoStream As CryptoStream
        Select Case Direction
            Case crypt.CryptoAction.ActionEncrypt
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(Me.fsOutput, cspRijndael.CreateEncryptor(bytKey, bytIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            Case crypt.CryptoAction.ActionDecrypt
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(Me.fsOutput, cspRijndael.CreateDecryptor(bytKey, bytIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        End Select
        While lngBytesProcessed < lngFileLength
            Dim intBytesInCurrentBlock As Integer = Me.fsInput.Read(bytBuffer, 0, 4096)

Warning --->     csCryptoStream.Write(bytBuffer, 0, intBytesInCurrentBlock)
            ' The following expression was wrapped in a unchecked-expression
            lngBytesProcessed += CLng(intBytesInCurrentBlock)
            ' The following expression was wrapped in a unchecked-expression
            Me.pbStatus.Value = CInt(Math.Round(CDec(lngBytesProcessed) / CDec(lngFileLength) * 100.0))
        End While
```

Comment: Assign it a value before you use it is probably the obvious thing to try first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare the `CryptoStream` as below:

   ```
    Dim csCryptoStream As CryptoStream = Nothing
   ```
2. Add a '`Case Else`' clause in your `Case/Select`
3. Before using this variable check if

   ```
   If Not IsNothing(csCryptoStream)
     '    ....
   End If
   ```

Comment: i got other error when i try to debugging : An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.NoStartupFormException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: @MuhammadFathan If you are getting the error on that line then try declaring it as 'New' i.e.  Dim csCryptoStream As New CryptoStream